# sorting hppc IntListArray without converting to int[]

Tags: java, sorting

in Java HPPC collections package,

there is `sort` function in `hiccup.sorting.IndirectSort` but it takes `int[]` as input.

Is there any way to sort `IntArrayList` directly? or I have to convert it to `int[]` every time?

Comment: what's HPPC ? can you elaborate?

Comment: @SMA a high performance java collections package

Comment: Don't know anything about HPPC, but just look in its [javadoc](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/download/hppc/0.6.0/api/). [`toArray()`](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/download/hppc/0.6.0/api/com/carrotsearch/hppc/IntArrayList.html#toArray()) returns your `IntArrayList` as `int[]`.  There is not need to convert anything.